# Save output in an xml file

Tags: php, xml

How to save the web content of the below link into an xml file? Below code is not working for me.

```
<?php
$url = "https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/ae0324ff-e1a5-4a77-9783-f41248bfa975/boats?status=on";
copy($url, "file.xml");
?>
```

Comment: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can download the contents of the given link to file.xml via Curl:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/ae0324ff-e1a5-4a77-9783-f41248bfa975/boats?status=on';
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/file.xml', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: what if curl is inaccesible? :)

Comment: Correct, Curl should be installed but hey, we can go on and on and on and on... What if PHP isn't installed, what if a firewall is blocking his outgoing connection, ...

Comment: Your solution won't work in such case too :P

Comment: Feel free to accept the solution. Next time, try to look for a solution first before posting it ;)

Comment: it just displays the output on browser but it doesn't store the data in xml file even after using $ch->save('file.xml');

Comment: Updated the answer, added CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('http://www.example.com');
$dom->save('filename.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
function savefile($filename,$data){
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
}

$data = file_get_contents('your link');
savefile('file.xml',$data);
```

Comment: thanks!! but getting an error as Can't open file..

Comment: It's because you don't have privilege to write in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 functions [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents);

**file_get_contents** - gets the content of file, A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.

**file_put_contents** - put the contents of second argument to a file specified in first argument

```
 <?php
  $url = "https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/ae0324ff-e1a5-4a77-9783-f41248bfa975/boats?status=on";
  file_put_contents('file.xml',file_get_contents($url));
  @chmod('file.xml', 0755); 
?>
```

Comment: There are so many security considerations to account for here. At the very least, please `chmod` file.xml so it's not world-executable.